# How to find the smallest flabby sheaf containing a given sheaf?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory

None of the spaces $C^k(\mathbb{R}^n)$, with $0 \leq k \leq \infty$, is a flabby sheaf. However, they are respectively contained in the smallest flabby sheaves $C^k_{nd} (\mathbb{R}^n)$ of functions $f: \mathbb{R}^n \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ for which there exist $\Gamma \subset \mathbb{R}^n$, $\Gamma$ closed and nowhere dense, such that $f$ restricted to $\mathbb{R}^n \setminus \Gamma$ is $C^k$-smooth.

Is any similar way known to construct flabby sheaves which contain given sheaves of functions defined on some topological space $X$?

Answer (score 3):

There is the "flabbification" or "flasquification" functor used in the Godement resolution.  Namely, given a sheaf $\mathcal{F}$ on $X$, let $\mathcal{F}_x$ be the stalk at a point $x$.  Then we define the sheaf $\Phi(\mathcal{F})$ to have sections $$\Gamma(U, \Phi(\mathcal{F}))=\prod_{x\in U} \mathcal{F}_x$$
with the obvious restriction maps.  (This is the same as endowing the etale space of $\mathcal{F}$ with the trivial topology and considering the sheaf of sections.)  There is a natural injection $\mathcal{F}\to \Phi(\mathcal{F})$ sending a section of $\mathcal{F}$ to its stalks.  Note that $\Phi$ is functorial; indeed, it is the right adjoint to the natural inclusion of the full subcategory (Flasque sheaves on $X$) $\hookrightarrow$ (Sheaves on $X$).

See for example [this Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Godement_resolution) or Godement's book on sheaf theory.

Edit:  One can also mimic your construction of $C^k_{nd}$ as follows.  Let $\mathcal{F}_{nd}$ have global sections given by $\bigcup \Gamma(X-\partial U, \mathcal{F})/\sim$ where the union is taken over all open sets $U$, and we say $(f, X-\partial U)\sim (f', X-\partial U')$ if $f=f'$ when restricted to $X-(\partial U\cup \partial U')$.  Then local sections will be restrictions of these global sections.  This will always be flabby, but will not necessarily have a morphism $\mathcal{F}\to \mathcal{F}_{nd}$ unless $\mathcal{F}$ has enough sections (for example, if $\mathcal{F}$ is fine, as in your example).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It seems however that the Godement flabbification is not the one which goes from $C^k$ to $C^k_{nd}$. And then, what is the difference ? More precisely, given a topological space $X$ and a sheaf $F$ of functions from open subsets $U \subseteq X$ to some set $E$, can one similar to the above, and not to Godement, construct some smallest flabby sheaf $F_{nd}$ of fucntions from open subsets $U \subseteq X$ to $E$, so that $F_{nd}$ extends $F$ ? 

Comment: I've added another construction to address your concerns.  I'm not convinced it's useful though--partly because I'm not sure what you mean by "smallest."  If you can come up with some functorial property you're looking for, that would help.

Comment: What I mean by "smallest" seems to happen with $C^k_{nd}$ when compared with $C^k$. Indeed, it seems that one cannot squeeze a flabby sheaf between the two of them, unless it is  $C^k_{nd}$ itslef. But then, perhaps, instead of the "smallest", one should rather talk about a "minimal" one ?

Comment: Sorry, I sent the previous comment from the office of Prof. Rosinger. ron l winger

Comment: Ah -- you claim that $C^k_{nd}$ has no flabby subsheaf containing $C^k$.  Can you prove this?  I think it's false.  For example, one can require that the $f|_\Gamma$ (where $\Gamma$ is your closed nowhere dense set) equals zero; this gives a smaller flabby sheaf containing $C^k$, unless I'm mistaken.

Comment: Dear Daniel, Yes, you are right. However, the resulting flabby sheaf is not so much smaller, and in fact, it is just about the same with C^k_{nd}. And to be more clear, one can in fact define C^k_{nd} from the start so that its functions are simply not defined on their respective singularity sets \Gamma.

Comment: Sure, as long as you identify functions appropriately (otherwise it's not a sheaf).  This is exactly the construction I give in my edit.